# How to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP without warning message?

Tags: asp.net

i have two web site: one HTTP site and other is HTTPS site. I will validate the credentials in HTTPS environment and will return to HTTP once authorized. The same is working fine in IE but in Mozilla im getting a warning as shown below.

[image]

How to avoid this warning message? currently im posting from HTTPS aspx page using java script to the HTTP page.

Comment: You can't. That is how browsers work. Nothing to do with asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are posting from https to http. If you instead did a GET and preferably a GET without parameters you might get around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with leppie. There is nothing is wrong with your code. It is how a good browser should work. Submitting sensitive data from a secure site to an unsecure site should not go without warning.

Recommended solution
Make both pages/sites "submitting page/site" and "submitted page/site" to run over HTTPS.

You can disable that warning message in Firefox which is not recommended. Go to FireFox>Option>Security>Warning Messages>Settings.